# How to fix TimeOut issue exception ssis package

Tags: ssis-2012

'openairBuffer.Buffer.CurrentRow' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.

Comment: Could you add some more information?

Comment: Actually i am runnning a ssis package every time i get  "[OpenAir Projecttask Service] Error: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters..  occured  in progress bar